# M.2 SSD not recognized by Windows 7 Ult installation

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, windows-installation

I've installed a Crucial M500 480GB SSD in the M.2 slot on an ASRock Z87 Extreme6 motherboard.  When I try to install Windows 7 Ult on it, the drive doesn't show; but with `diskpart`, it shows as `drive 0` (which I can select).  When I list the volumes, the Blu-Ray drive shows as `volume 0` and the SSD as `volume 1` (in both cases the SSD shows with size `0`).

All interactions I've tried on the SSD result in: 
 `Virtual Disk Service error: There is no media in the device.`

How can i get around this and install Windows on it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the ASROCK driver for when you go through the Windows Installation?

It could well be that Windows 7 does not recognise the SATA controller and you need to use the FLOPPY driver (as per older times of press F6 for driver) to be able to 'see' the controller, therefore hard drive, correctly?

Asrock site for your driver ... look down the list to SATA Floppy Image

http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z87%20Extreme6/?cat=Download&os=Win764

Comment: p.s. I would have done this as a comment to your question but I am not allowed to ... yet

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers but they weren't it.
When i switched the M.2 SSD to the second M.2 slot on the motherboard it worked just fine.
The Windows 7 installation process recognized the drive and it installed without a hitch.
Thanks anyway for your suggestions.
Frank.