# M.2 Sandisk x400 not recognized by Win10 install

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, bios, m.2

A few others had the same problem; no hardrive is found by install:

- fixed with Bios SATA mode configuration set to M.2 (my Bios does not have this option) [Windows 10 install not recognizing Samsung 850 Evo m.2 hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1159904/windows-10-install-not-recognizing-samsung-850-evo-m-2-hard-drive)
- use 2nd M.2 slot on motherboard (my mb does not have an m.2 slot) [M.2 SSD not recognized by Windows 7 Ult installation](https://superuser.com/questions/864403/m-2-ssd-not-recognized-by-windows-7-ult-installation)
- good overview of M.2 PCIe compatibility https://us.hardware.info/reviews/6274/4/pci-express-ssds-review-8-models-compared-compatibilityn
- I cross posted to Reddit Build a PC https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/5vel7f/pcie_drives_compatible_with_asus_m4a87td_amd_8/

This is my hardware:

- ASUS M4A87TD/USB3 (AMD 8 series chipset) motherboard BIOS American Megatrends (v02.61) version 1102 https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A87TDUSB3/
- Sandisk x400 M.2 (NVMe) https://www.sandisk.com/business/computing/x400
- Wings PX1 PCIe to M.2 adapter http://www.angelbird.com/en/prod/wings-px1-1117/ ([the Sandisk x400 is not on the PX1 compatibility list](http://www.angelbird.com/en/prod/wings-px1-1117/#technical-specifications))
- Previously this computer had a Revodrive x1 (PCIe drive) that booted without an issue.

I tried:

- the diskpart tool suggested by sandisk https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12588/~/ssd-detected-in-bios-but-not-detected-by-os-installation
- looking for the Wings X1 driver but there is not one.
- <s>I tried the Intel Rapid Storage Technology but all the drivers are listed as non compatible with this computer's hardware.</s> (IRST is for intel hardware only, relates to RIAD, and Win10 has native M.2 support), maybe they meant the Intel NVMe driver https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26451/Intel-SSD-Data-Center-Family-for-NVMe-Drivers
- updated AMD Series 8 chipset driver for RAID (in hope it has a PCIe m.2 driver); no luck
- updated to the latest BIOS 2011/04/22 (nothing about PCIe and did not solve)
  -- Improve the performance of SATA5/6 Ports under IDE Mode.
  -- Improve EPU function (energy efficiency).

I ordered a Samsung SM951 (AHCI) M.2 (it is on the approved PX1 list and uses the AHCI driver) - it will be here on the 27th.

Comment: If your motherboard doesn't have a M.2 connector, is there a reason, your using a M.2 SSD?  *It is very likely your problems are because of the adapter.*  "I did not try the Intel Rapid Storage Technology since it is not offered for Win10" - Yeah, it actually is.

Comment: [Intel® Rapid Storage Technology (Intel® RST) RAID Driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26361/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-RAID-Driver).  Of course unless you want a RAID this driver isn't required.

Comment: Please clarify: `M.2 Samsung x400` or `Sandisk x400 M.2`

Comment: If you have the Samsung device, you can try using the [Samsung NVMe Driver](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html).  If that doesn't work try the IRST drivers as I previously provided.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  I linked you to Windows 10 IRST compatible drivers.

Comment: There a reason, you are trying to install IRST on AMD hardware, IRST does not apply to your hardware.  Would have helped to mention that fact, within the body, instead of just a link to the motherboard.  I assumed, that you understood, IRST can only be used on Intel hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M.2 is a form factor, not an interface: "Buses exposed through the M.2 connector are PCI Express 3.0, Serial ATA (SATA) 3.0 and USB 3.0" ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2))

It appears (from Newegg and Sandisk) that the Sandisk x400 uses the SATA interface.

The Samsung evo 960 on the "approved drives" list on the adapter card site is an M.2 device that uses the PCIe interface. I did not run down the full list to check them all.

One side-track link I followed to Dell support states: "Note : Not all SSDs with an M.2 Interface are PCIe SSDs." ([link](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN300820/what-is-a-pcie-ssd-and-can-i-use-it-as-a-boot-drive-for-a-windows-install-on-a-dell-pc??lang=EN))

So I strongly suspect that you simply have a compatibility problem between the card which is for PCIe M.2 devices and an SATA M.2 SSD device.

Comment: I ordered a Samsung evo 960 and a Samsung SM951 (AHCI); between these three cards hopefully one will work.

Comment: ^ I ended up buying three motherboards (one has an M.2 socket) and three M.2 drives (mix of SATA and PCIe and of NVMe and AHCI) plus a PCIe adapter.  I had one that works (board with M.2 socket and I don't recall which M.2 drive), but, the CPU was not supported. I found another solution (PCIe adapter) that would have worked with some BIOS mods (I chickened out - at that point I grabbed my backup plan, dual SATA3 SSDs in RAID0).

Comment: ^^ Nice explanation here http://www.computershopper.com/feature/2017-guide-the-best-m.2-solid-state-drives-tested key advice "verify with the board maker that an M.2 SSD of the bus type you are considering will be bootable"